# Error with adding inputs for order total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to add input with class of "total" together and then display it in the field #total_price. The problem is that my code is simply concatenating the numbers instead of adding them together, so instead of 2 and 2 resulting in 4 it results in 22. If anyone can explain where I went wrong it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

HTML snippet to give you an idea:

```
<tr>
                            <td>
                                <select id="Board_D" class="service">
                                    <option value="select">Board Pickets</option>
                                    <option value="1">Board Pickets on 1X4 6' Tall</option>
                                    <option value="2">Board Pickets on 1X6 6' Tall</option>
                                    <option value="3">Board Pickets on 1X4 8' Tall</option>
                                    <option value="4">Board Pickets on 1X6 8' Tall</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>$<input id="Board_C" /></td>
                            <td><input id="Board_Q" class="service" /></td>
                            <td>$<input id="Board_A" class="total" /></td>
                        </tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '#manualOverrideNo, [class="total"], [class="standard"], [class="service"]', function(){
    if($('#manualOverrideNo').prop('checked')) {

        /*total_cost = 9;
        $("#total_price").val(total_cost);*/
        var sum = '';
            /*Go through each input with class of 'total'*/

        $(".total").each(function() {
            /*Add only if value is a number*/
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $("#total_price").val(sum);
    }
});
```

Comment: try declaring `sum` as `0` / `var sum = 0;`

Comment: "" + 2 + 2 = 22,
0 + 2 + 2 = 4

Comment: @Spokey got it right. If you try to add stuff to a string it will compute as a string and perform concatenation. if you set it to 0 you are stating it is a numerical value and the interpreter will perform math.

Comment: Thank y'all! I kept thinking I had an error in my logic. Please feel free to post that answer @spokey and I will happily accept it.